# Display UIPickerView on top of InAppBrowser (Cordova)

Tags: cordova

I'm using the Cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-listpicker" which is the native UIPickerView for selecting items. It works well however I'm using InAppBrowser to display a web app and when calling the listpicker plugin the picker opens behind the InAppBrowser. So currently I have to hide the browser to show the picker. Is there a way to show the picker above the InAppBrowser?

```
    inAppBrowser.hide();

    window.plugins.listpicker.showPicker(config,
        function(item) {
            alert("You have selected " + item);
            inAppBrowser.show()
        },
        function() {
            alert("You have cancelled");
            inAppBrowser.show()
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InAppBrowser is shown as a modal view over the webview, and the cordova-plugin-listpicker is added as a subview on the webview superview, so the InAppBrowser will always be over it.

You can edit the cordova-plugin-listpicker code to get the current view on top instead of the webview superview and add itself to it, or to present the picker as a modal view controller also on to of the InAppBrowser

This is the method you should change https://github.com/roberthovhannisyan/PhoneGap-Plugin-ListPicker/blob/master/src/ios/ListPicker.m#L111

Comment: If the plugins get updated will the change be overwritten?

Comment: ^ (Not sure if I need to tag)

Comment: Yeah, best choice is to fork the plugin repo and make the changes there, so you use your fork instead of the original plugin. Then you can try to send a PR and if they accept it you can continue using the original plugin and you can update safely. If not, you will have to keep your fork up to date by cherry-picking their commits into your fork.